# Cognito to Lambda sync trigger not firing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-lambda

I have authentication working with Cognito and I have a sync trigger set to call a Lambda function. This function is not called when the identity is initially created. The function is only called if the record already exists. If I call a dataset.synchronize() later, the trigger does fire correctly.

Does the initial creation of an identity fire the sync trigger or must I call dataset.synchronize() in my client code to kick it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito events are currently fired on dataset synchronization only, they would not be invoked upon an identity creation. To fire it, you must call synchronize.